# Discord.py Making a varable available to mutliple commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to write a bot to do counting in a server. I have not worked in python before and as such am trying to learn as I go. When calling !current the bot doesn't respond with anything it is just silent and it seems to be something to do with the count variable. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
#Counting Class
class count:
    def __init__(self, cur_channel, number): 
        self.cur_channel = cur_channel
        self.number = number

    def displayCount(self):
        return self.number

# Setting the command prefix
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

# Command Definitions
# Start Count Command
@bot.command(name='sc', help='Starts the count for the current channel')
async def startCount(ctx):
    bot.temp = count(ctx.channel, 0)
    print(f'\nA count has been started')
    channel = bot.temp.cur_channel

    await channel.send(ctx.channel)

# Check Count Command
@bot.command(name='current')
async def check_count(ctx):
    count = bot.temp.displayCount()
    print(f'\nThe count is: ' + count)
    await ctx.send('The current count is ' + count)
```

Comment: do you have an error handler that blocks the error? if so, comment it out and edit the error to the question please. And does `!sc` work?  I think it has to do with the `bot.temp = count()`, i dont think this is possible

Comment: !sc does work and prints out the channel name correctly. Figured it out! A previous tutorial had me create an error handler but it was only for when a user didn't have permissions. Once commenting it out the error is that it didn't like that a int was being passed into the string. Is there a better way to pass variables between functions other than this method?

Comment: you could also use `global variables`, but in both ways the stored data will be removed if the bot restarts - the best way is to store everything in a json file or database

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to use `bot.xxx` doing this it will cache the value into a global variable that you can use elsewhere. It can be a dict or a list if you want also.

invoke command `a` before `b`

```py
@bot.command()
async def a(ctx):
    bot.something = 12345

@bot.command()
async def b(ctx):
    await ctx.send(bot.something)
```